# Trouble with making a Header Move with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not HW but a challenge from a coding book I am using to try to learn Javascript.

The challenge is to make the header move 200 px left, then 200 px down, 200px left and then 200px up. I have tried multiple ways but I get errors or it jumps or I cannot get it to decrease. I've put the basic outline of what I know I need to do here (which just brings it diagonally). I appreciate any help!

Thanks,

Daniel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Interactive programming</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Hello world!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    var leftOffset = 0;
    var moveDown=0
    var moveHeading = function () {
      if(leftOffset<=200){
        $("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset });
        leftOffset++;
      }
    };

    var moveHeadingDown= function (){
      if(moveDown<=200 ){
        $("#heading").offset({ top: moveDown });
        moveDown++;
       }
     };

    var moveHeadingLeft= function (){
      if (leftOffset===200){
        $("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset });
        leftOffset--;
      }
    };
    var moveHeadingUp= function (){
      if (moveDown===200){
        $("#heading").offset({ top: moveDown });
        moveDown--;
      }
    }

    setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
    setInterval(moveHeadingDown, 30);
    setInterval(moveHeadingLeft, 30);
    setInterval(moveHeadingUp, 30);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier using Jquery animate() function.

Example:

```
leftValue = -200; // pixels
bottomValue = -200; // pixels
timeAnim = 1000; // seconds
typeAnim = 'swing';

$("#heading").animate({
  left: leftValue
}, timeAnim, typeAnim,

  function() {
    $("#heading").animate({
      bottom: bottomValue
    }, timeAnim, typeAnim,

    function() {
      // Next function
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! Unfortunately, I am looking to do it using the setInterval method as that was the challenge in the book. Do you have any suggestions for how to do it with setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var offleft=0;
 var offtop=0;

function position() {
   $('#heading').css('margin-top',offtop+'px');
   $('#heading').css('margin-left',offleft+'px');
}
$(function() {
  $({i:0}).animate({i:1},{
   duration: 300,
   easing: 'linear',
   step: function(now) {
      if(now<=0.25) {
         offleft = now*4*200;
      }
      else if(now<=0.5) {
         offtop = (now-0.25)*4*200;
      }
      else if(now<=0.75) {
         offleft = (now*-1+0.75)*4*200;
      }
      else {
         offtop = (now*-1+1)*4*200;
      }
      position();
   }
  });
});
```

Is that what you wanted? I think, it moves the element down, than right, up and left by each time 200px.

Please reach out to me if you find it useful and it actually works :)

Sincerely Sebastian

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! Unfortunately though the challenge was asking for using setIntervals to move it. For example this moves it left repeatedly on a loop however I want it to stop and then move down and continue.

Comment: 'var leftOffset = 0;
var moveHeading = function () {
  $("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset });
  leftOffset++;
  if (leftOffset> 200) {
    leftOffset=0
  }
};


setInterval(moveHeading, 30);'